# Gradient Descent is not converging for very large values in a small dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I am trying to write a program to calculate the slope and the intercept of a linear regression model but when I am running more than 10 iterations, the gradient descent function gives the `np.nan` value for both intercept as well as slope.

Below is my implementation

```
def get_gradient_at_b(x, y, b, m):
  N = len(x)
  diff = 0
  for i in range(N):
    x_val = x[i]
    y_val = y[i]
    diff += (y_val - ((m * x_val) + b))
  b_gradient = -(2/N) * diff  
  return b_gradient

def get_gradient_at_m(x, y, b, m):
  N = len(x)
  diff = 0
  for i in range(N):
      x_val = x[i]
      y_val = y[i]
      diff += x_val * (y_val - ((m * x_val) + b))
  m_gradient = -(2/N) * diff  
  return m_gradient

def step_gradient(b_current, m_current, x, y, learning_rate):
    b_gradient = get_gradient_at_b(x, y, b_current, m_current)
    m_gradient = get_gradient_at_m(x, y, b_current, m_current)
    b = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)
    m = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient)
    return [b, m]

def gradient_descent(x, y, learning_rate, num_iterations):
  b = 0
  m = 0
  for i in range(num_iterations):
    b, m = step_gradient(b, m, x, y, learning_rate)
  return [b,m]
```

I am running it on the following data:

```
a=[3.87656018e+11, 4.10320300e+11, 4.15730874e+11, 4.52699998e+11,
       4.62146799e+11, 4.78965491e+11, 5.08068952e+11, 5.99592902e+11,
       6.99688853e+11, 8.08901077e+11, 9.20316530e+11, 1.20111177e+12,
       1.18695276e+12, 1.32394030e+12, 1.65661707e+12, 1.82304993e+12,
       1.82763786e+12, 1.85672212e+12, 2.03912745e+12, 2.10239081e+12,
       2.27422971e+12, 2.60081824e+12]
b=[3.3469950e+10, 3.4784980e+10, 3.3218720e+10, 3.6822490e+10,
       4.4560290e+10, 4.3826720e+10, 5.2719430e+10, 6.3842550e+10,
       8.3535940e+10, 1.0309053e+11, 1.2641405e+11, 1.6313218e+11,
       1.8529536e+11, 1.7875143e+11, 2.4981555e+11, 3.0596392e+11,
       3.0040058e+11, 3.1440530e+11, 3.1033848e+11, 2.6229109e+11,
       2.7585243e+11, 3.0352616e+11]

print(gradient_descent(a, b, 0.01, 100))
#result --> [nan, nan]
```

When I run the `gradient_descent` function on a dataset with smaller values, it gives the correct answers. Also I was able to obtain the intercept and slope for the above data with from `sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression`

Any help will be appreciated in figuring out why the result is `[nan, nan]` instead of giving me the correct intercept and slope.

Comment: how can you get closer to the reason?

try printing out the relevant values during each iteration.

Comment: @KevinWang Yes I tried that but after 15 iterations, both values seems to reach infinity. So i suspect that they are moving in the wrong direction. Also the result fronm ```sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression``` is ```intercept --> 190277205197.76184, slope --> 6.232237596577799 ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the learning rate. Since the values in `a` and `b` are so large (>= `1e11`), the learning rate needs be approximately `1e-25` for this to even do the gradient descent, else it will randomly overshoot because of large gradients of `a` and `b`.

```
b, m = gradient_descent(a, b, 5e-25, 100)
print(b, m)
Out: -3.7387067636195266e-13 0.13854551291084335
```

Comment: That's a great observation but I am still not getting the correct result for my b and m value as I can get from other built in methods for linear regression. Could you help me tune the learning rate so that I can get to the correct answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you try kind of normalization as the values of both inputs and output posess a quite large difference:
Let's say  2.60081824e+12 and 3.87656018e+11.

Try:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
a_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(a)
b_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(b)
```

Before ur GD functions!!emphasized text